# Why does the data type vary for assignment instead of direct checking?

Tags: python, types

Python shows different data type for seemingly similar inputs.

While assigning a value to a variable like this, I get a tuple:

```py
>>> x = 1,
>>> type(x)
>>> <class 'tuple'>
```

However when I do the same thing in the following way, it shows a different data type:

```py
>>> type(1,)
>>> <class 'int'>
```

How and why do these two differ from each other?

Comment: The comma in `type(1,)` is being interpreted as part of the function call (ie a trailing comma in the arg list), not as part of the first arg.  Try `type((1,))`.  In the expression `x = 1,` there’s no way to interpret the comma except as part of a tuple, so the extra parens aren’t needed to disambiguate it.

Comment: If you want to guarantee you have a tuple, wrap it in parentheses.  Without them, in some contexts they are implicit, and in some they are not.  The same is true for generators, for which you can sometimes omit the parentheses but sometimes need them.

Comment: When there is ambiguity, Python assumes a function call.  So `foo(1, 2, 3, 4)` is calling `foo` with four arguments, not with the two arguments `1, 2` and `3, 4`.  Since Python lets you put a comma at the end of an argument list, `type(1,)` is just an argument list of one value.

Comment: @FrankYellin thankyou for the explanation! That is exactly what I was curious about.